CiviDiscout Menu not showing up
I am running CiviCRM 5.63.1 and CiviDiscount 3.8.10.  The CiviDiscount is showing up on the menu but is not allowing me to choose any options.  I have tried uninstalling CiviDiscount and reinstalling and the same thing.
.



Welcome to StackExchange! It looks like you've attempted to add a screenshot as a comment but I'm unable to see it. Could you add it directly to the question - edit the question and drag and drop the screenshot in.
